# How do I put an if statement inside the echoed html of another if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I'm building a menu and I want it to be controlled by user level.  I have an if statement that echoes the link to show.   However, instead of showing the entire sub-menu, I want to break it down into more if statements.   How do I do this?

Here is my code if I don't make any sense:

```
  <?php
 if (!isset($logged)) {
 echo "";
 } else {
     echo "<li><a href=\"#\">Useful Info</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href=\"offices.php\">Directory</a></li>"
   if ($metric == "admins" || $metric == "management" || $metric == "executives" || $metric == "god") {
   echo
   "<li><a href=\"#\">Services Sub Menu 2</a></li>"
   }
   "<li><a href=\"about.php\">About</a></li>
   <li><a href=\"#\">Services Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>";
 }
 ?>
```

Here is my code after answers:

```
  <?php
 if (!isset($logged)) {
 echo "";
 } else {
     echo "<li><a href=\"#\">Useful Info</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href=\"offices.php\">Directory</a></li>";
   if ($metric == "admins" || $metric == "management" || $metric == "executives" || $metric == "god") {
   echo
   "<li><a href=\"#\">Services Sub Menu 2</a></li>";
   }
   else {
       echo "";
   }
   "<li><a href=\"about.php\">About</a></li>
   <li><a href=\"#\">Services Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: This bug highlights the importance of choosing and **always** using an indentation style. There are a few to pick from, I prefer "1tbs". Look at the samples, pick one, then become a fanatic for it. Like to the degree you consider code "broken" if it isn't indented. Seriously. Every line, even HTML strings. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style -- go forth and choose wisely. Also, when developing, turn error reporting on `E_ALL|E_STRICT`. It will tell you what line a parse error is on, and any other issues in your code. Put it in a log or turn it off for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing semicolon (`;`).

```
echo "<li><a href=\"#\">Useful Info</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href=\"offices.php\">Directory</a></li>";
                                                 ^^^^
```

AND

```
echo
   "<li><a href=\"#\">Services Sub Menu 2</a></li>";
                                                  ^^^^
```

**EDIT**

You are missing to add `echo`

```
echo "<li><a href=\"about.php\">About</a></li>
   <li><a href=\"#\">Services Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>";
```

Comment: Thank you.  You'd think I'd know to look for semi-colons by now.

Comment: Hey, I've fixed it and updated my code.  Now it shows all links after this block as submenus of "Useful Info".   Am I supposed to use concatenation somewhere or something?

Comment: @SherwoodPro check my updated answer, you are missing to add `echo`

Comment: Oh, so even if it is picking up where it left off - I still have to echo it then?

Comment: @SherwoodPro yes, you need to echo every time to print html.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it with echo you can do it like this.

You are missing some `;` and one `echo` statement.

```
  <?php
 if (!isset($logged)) {
 echo "";
 } else {
     echo "<li><a href=\"#\">Useful Info</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href=\"offices.php\">Directory</a></li>";
   if ($metric == "admins" || $metric == "management" || $metric == "executives" || $metric == "god") {
   echo
   "<li><a href=\"#\">Services Sub Menu 2</a></li>";
   }
   echo "<li><a href=\"about.php\">About</a></li>
   <li><a href=\"#\">Services Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Ah.  Stupid semi-colons.  : )  Thanks!